# Kdevelop 5 + kdev-control-flow-graph

Tags: c++, plugins, kdevelop, kparts

I successfully build and installed kdev-control-flow-graph plugin after forking from [sandsmark/kdev-control-flow-graph](https://github.com/sandsmark/kdev-control-flow-graph) into my own [fljx/kdev-control-flow-graph](https://github.com/fljx/kdev-control-flow-graph) branch with minimal changes.

When I try to enable kdev-control-flow-graph view, though, I receive the error below:

[image: KGraphViewer KPart error]

*"Unable to create a KGraphViewer instance, please verify that a compatible version is installed."*

I am running on Kubuntu 16.04 with KDevelop 5.1.1 and kgraphviewer is installed:

```
# apt search kgraphviewer
Sorting... Pronto
Full Text Search... Pronto
kgraphviewer/xenial,now 4:2.1.90-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
  GraphViz dot graph viewer

kgraphviewer-dbg/xenial 4:2.1.90-0ubuntu2 amd64
  GraphViz dot graph viewer for KDE 4 debug files

kgraphviewer-dev/xenial,now 4:2.1.90-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
  GraphViz dot graph viewer - devel files

libkgraphviewer2/xenial,now 4:2.1.90-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
  GraphViz dot graph viewer - libs
```

Then I build `KGraphViewer` from github and my system now has:

```
# find /usr -iname "*kgraphviewer*.so*" -ls
 10571222      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           22 Ago 14  2015 /usr/lib/libkgraphviewer.so.2 -> libkgraphviewer.so.2.1
 10571221    712 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       728288 Ago 14  2015 /usr/lib/libkgraphviewer.so.2.1
 10558158   2868 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root      2935024 Ago 17 16:32 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkgraphviewer.so.3
 11170876      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           57 Ago 17 16:37 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kdevplatform/27/kgraphviewerpart.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kgraphviewerpart.so
 10748549    180 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       181312 Ago 17 16:32 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kgraphviewerpart.so
 10558159      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           20 Ago 17 16:33 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkgraphviewer.so -> libkgraphviewer.so.3
 10571223     60 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        60392 Ago 14  2015 /usr/lib/kde4/kgraphviewerpart.so
 10571224      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           20 Ago 14  2015 /usr/lib/libkgraphviewer.so -> libkgraphviewer.so.2
```

Could anybody please give me any hints on how to make my plugin correctly find `KGraphViewer KPart`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

KDE dev reporting in.

KGraphViewer is embedded into other applications using KParts framework. Porting KGraphViewer's KPart to Qt5/KF5 is near to release. The bad news is that kdev-control-flow-graph don't work with new KGraphViewer, so this plugin needs to be updated too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @arrowd. I am afraid I didn't understand you, though. I have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kgraphviewerpart.so` that was installed from github sources (master) and it links against Qt5 / KF5 libraries.Isn't this library the needed KGrphViewer KPart? Could you please point me any links where I can learn more?

Comment: Yes, this is right library, but KDevelop's plugin doesn't work with it yet. So, for now it is impossible to use kdev-control-flow-graph plugin in KDevelop 5.

Comment: :( this plugin is something I really miss from KDevelop 4. How can I help? Thanks again @arrowd.

Comment: Join `#kdevelop` channel on Freenode and get in touch with `frinring`. He can explain what needs to be done in detail.